# Why am I getting "Use of uninitialized value $num in subtraction"?

Tags: perl

I'm working on a Perl module using XS to bind to a C library.  When I build it, I'm getting a warning message saying `Use of uninitialized value $num in subtraction (-) at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14.2/ExtUtils/ParseXS.pm line 1769, <GEN8> line 90.`

This is triggered by the code generated by [ExtUtils::Constant](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aConstant). Commenting out the `INCLUDE: const-xs.inc` line in Foo.xs removes the warning.  But I don't know whether the bug is in [ExtUtils::ParseXS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aParseXS) or in ExtUtils::Constant.

I'm using ExtUtils::Constant 0.23, ExtUtils::ParseXS 3.15, Module::Build 0.38, and Perl 5.14.2.

I've managed to pare it down to a reasonably [small test case](https://github.com/madsen/ParseXS-ExtUtils-Constant-bug) that doesn't require any external C library, but it's still too large to post here.  I've placed it in a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/madsen/ParseXS-ExtUtils-Constant-bug).  To reproduce the bug, clone the repo, type `perl Build.PL` and then `./Build`.  You should see:

```
$ perl Build.PL
Regenerating constants...
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Foo' version '0.01'
$ ./Build 
Building Foo
Use of uninitialized value $num in subtraction ...
gcc ... -o lib/Foo.o lib/Foo.c
ExtUtils::Mkbootstrap::Mkbootstrap('blib/arch/auto/Foo/Foo.bs')
gcc ... -o blib/arch/auto/Foo/Foo.so lib/Foo.o
```

You'll only see "Regenerating constants..." if you have ExtUtils::Constant installed.  You shouldn't need it to reproduce the bug, because I've added the generated files to the repo.

Whatever the problem is, it doesn't seem to stop the code from working, because the included test does pass.

**Update:** I've reported this as [RT#112776](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=112776).  The consensus seems to be it's a bug in ExtUtils::ParseXS, but the solution is not clear.

Comment: I'm going to guess a bug in the module.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, which module?

Comment: Dunno. I don't have the code in front of me to do a `grep '$num'` on.

Comment: Debugger says the variable becomes undef on line 1214 in sub `INPUT_handler` while parsing the line `const char *    s = SvPV(sv, len);` in `lib/const-xs.inc`.